# Creating Mappings for Index Interconnections in ElasticSearch: How to Establish Relationships Between Tables?

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-7

I've successfully uploaded 10 CSV tables to ElasticSearch to create a Kibana dashboard. However, since these tables are interlinked with foreign keys, they have been transformed into JSON (NoSQL) format. I'm now looking for guidance on how to establish mappings for relationships, such as one-to-many and one-to-one, similar to what we do in relational databases. What are the recommended approaches to achieve this in ElasticSearch?

I tried to create dashboard with multiple Index but it is show one index(table) at a time for visuals